# Improve Export PDF export speed

Tags: arcobjects

I have an ArcObjects VBA code that exports a series of group layers listed in a table (also listed in the table of contents) to pdf.  For each group layer/export the legend also changes to represent the specific group layer that is exporting out.  When I added the legend refresh portion of the code each group layer export took about 10X slower to export (before it took about 3-4 sec to export each group layer, now it takes well over 40 sec).  I'm curious if anybody has any suggestions on how I may change the code around to increase the speed again.  Here is the code.

```
'Export to pdfs
Dim pFSO2 As FileSystemObject
Dim pNewFolderc As folder

Set pFSO2 = New FileSystemObject

If (pFSO2.FolderExists("C:\TMP") = False) Then
    Set pNewFolderc = pFSO2.CreateFolder("C:\TMP")
Else
    Set pNewFolderc = pFSO2.GetFolder("C:\TMP")
End If

Dim pAV As IActiveView
Dim pPageLayout As IPageLayout

Dim pEnum As IEnumLayer
Dim pLayer As ILayer
Dim pGLayer As IGroupLayer

Dim pFLayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pFClass As IFeatureClass

Dim pGxLayer As IGxLayer, pGxNewLayer As IGxLayer, pGxFile As IGxFile
Dim pGrpLayer As IGroupLayer

Dim pStdTableColl As IStandaloneTableCollection
Dim pStdTable As IStandaloneTable
Dim pTable As ITable
Dim pTableSort As ITableSort
Dim pTblSortLyrs As ITableSort
Dim pRow As IRow
Dim pRowLyrs As IRow
Dim pDataStat As IDataStatistics
Dim pCursor As ICursor
Dim pLyrCursor As ICursor
Dim pQf As IQueryFilter
    
Dim lngFldLayerName As Long
Dim lngFldPath As Long
Dim lngFldGroupOrder As Long
Dim lngFldGroupName As Long
Dim lngFldGroupTOCOrder As Long
Dim lngFldGroupVis As Long
Dim i As Integer

Dim strLayerName As String

Dim strPath As String
Dim lngGroupOrder As Long
Dim strGroupName As String
Dim lngGroupTOCOrder As Long
Dim blnGroupVis As Boolean
    
Dim pEnumVar As IEnumVariantSimple, value As Variant

Dim pODGSLyr As ODGSLayer

Dim pGrphcon As IGraphicsContainer
Dim pElem As IElement
Dim pTxtElem As ITextElement
    
strOMSIUAComplaintNo = txtfoldername.Text

If cboAPPNO.Text = "" Or txtfoldername.Text = "" Then
 MsgBox "Please select APPNO well feature"
 Exit Sub
Else

 Dim intresponse2 As Integer
 
 intresponse2 = MsgBox("Export pdfs?", vbYesNo)
   If intresponse2 = vbNo Then
    UserForm1.Hide
    cboAPPNO.Text = ""
    txtfoldername = ""
    Exit Sub
   ElseIf intresponse2 = vbYes Then
    UserForm1.Caption = "Exporting, please wait..."
    
'Goto Page layout
Set pPageLayout = m_pMxDoc.PageLayout
Set m_pMxDoc.ActiveView = pPageLayout

'Find Basemap Group and DRG layers and turn both of them on
Set m_pMap = m_pMxDoc.FocusMap
Set pEnum = m_pMap.Layers

Set pLayer = pEnum.Next

Do Until pLayer Is Nothing
    If pLayer.Name = "Basemaps" Then pLayer.Visible = True
    If pLayer.Name Like "DRG*" Then pLayer.Visible = True
    Set pLayer = pEnum.Next
Loop

'Turn off all the group layers
Set pStdTableColl = m_pMap
For i = 0 To pStdTableColl.StandaloneTableCount - 1
    Set pStdTable = pStdTableColl.StandaloneTable(i)
    If pStdTable.Name = "ODGSLAYERS" Then
        Set pTable = pStdTable
        lngFldLayerName = pTable.FindField("LAYERNAME")
        lngFldPath = pTable.FindField("PATH")
        lngFldGroupOrder = pTable.FindField("GROUPORDER")
        lngFldGroupName = pTable.FindField("GROUPNAME")
        lngFldGroupTOCOrder = pTable.FindField("GROUPTOCORDER")
        lngFldGroupVis = pTable.FindField("GROUPVISABLE")
    End If
Next i

If pStdTable Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Sort the Table
Set pTableSort = New TableSort
With pTableSort
    .Fields = "GROUPTOCORDER, GROUPNAME"
    .Ascending("GROUPTOCORDER") = True
    .Ascending("GROUPNAME") = True
    Set .QueryFilter = Nothing
    Set .Table = pTable
End With
pTableSort.Sort Nothing

Set pCursor = pTableSort.Rows

'Find Unique Values in the Table
Set pDataStat = New DataStatistics
pDataStat.field = "GROUPNAME"
Set pDataStat.Cursor = pCursor

Set pEnumVar = pDataStat.UniqueValues
value = pEnumVar.Next

Do Until IsEmpty(value)
    pEnum.Reset
    Set pLayer = pEnum.Next
    Do Until pLayer Is Nothing
        If pLayer.Name = value Then pLayer.Visible = False
        Set pLayer = pEnum.Next
    Loop
    strLayerName = value
    value = pEnumVar.Next
Loop

'Now cycle through the group layers, turn them on one by one and export the PDF file
'First find the Title on the map

Set pGrphcon = pPageLayout
pGrphcon.Reset
Set pElem = pGrphcon.Next

Do Until pElem Is Nothing
    If TypeOf pElem Is ITextElement Then
        Set pTxtElem = pElem
        If pTxtElem.Text = "OMSIUA Layers" Then Exit Do
    End If
    Set pElem = pGrphcon.Next
Loop

Set pStdTableColl = m_pMap
For i = 0 To pStdTableColl.StandaloneTableCount - 1
    Set pStdTable = pStdTableColl.StandaloneTable(i)
    If pStdTable.Name = "ODGSLAYERS" Then
        Set pTable = pStdTable
        lngFldLayerName = pTable.FindField("LAYERNAME")
        lngFldPath = pTable.FindField("PATH")
        lngFldGroupOrder = pTable.FindField("GROUPORDER")
        lngFldGroupName = pTable.FindField("GROUPNAME")
        lngFldGroupTOCOrder = pTable.FindField("GROUPTOCORDER")
        lngFldGroupVis = pTable.FindField("GROUPVISABLE")
    End If
Next i

If pStdTable Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Sort the Table
Set pTableSort = New TableSort
With pTableSort
    .Fields = "GROUPTOCORDER, GROUPNAME"
    .Ascending("GROUPTOCORDER") = True
    .Ascending("GROUPNAME") = True
    Set .QueryFilter = Nothing
    Set .Table = pTable
End With

pTableSort.Sort Nothing

Set pCursor = pTableSort.Rows

'Find Unique Values in the Table
Set pDataStat = New DataStatistics
pDataStat.field = "GROUPNAME"
Set pDataStat.Cursor = pCursor
Set pEnumVar = pDataStat.UniqueValues

value = pEnumVar.Next
Do Until IsEmpty(value)
    pEnum.Reset
    Set pLayer = pEnum.Next
    Do Until pLayer Is Nothing
        If pLayer.Name = value Then
            pLayer.Visible = True
            strLayerName = value
            pTxtElem.Text = strLayerName

''''''''''''Cal to ExportActiveView, Module''''''''''''''''
            Call ExportActiveView.ExportActiveView(strOMSIUAComplaintNo & "_" & _     strLayerName)

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

            pLayer.Visible = False
        End If
        
        'Refresh legend  '<<<<<<<<<<<<< Refresh legend portion
        Dim pMxDoc2 As IMxDocument
        Dim pPageLayout2 As IPageLayout
        Dim pGC2 As IGraphicsContainer
        Dim pElem2 As IElement
        Dim pMSF2 As IMapSurroundFrame
        Dim pMS2 As IMapSurround

        Set pMxDoc2 = ThisDocument
        Set pPageLayout2 = pMxDoc2.PageLayout
        Set pGC2 = pPageLayout2
        pGC2.Reset

        Set pElem2 = pGC2.Next
            Do Until pElem2 Is Nothing
            If TypeOf pElem2 Is IMapSurroundFrame Then
                Set pMSF2 = pElem2
                Set pMS2 = pMSF2.MapSurround
            pMS2.Refresh
            pMxDoc2.ActiveView.Refresh

            End If
            Set pElem2 = pGC2.Next

            Loop

        Set pLayer = pEnum.Next

    Loop
    value = pEnumVar.Next
Loop

pTxtElem.Text = "OMSIUA Layers"

Set m_pMxDoc.ActiveView = m_pMap

m_pMxDoc.UpdateContents
m_pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh

End If
End If
```

Comment: Your code has the Long Method Smell.  Refactoring it would make it easier for people to help you. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html

Comment: "Long Method" meaning, I should break it up into several seperate Subs, one calling from the other? thx

Comment: yes, that would help.

Comment: do you have any transparencies on your layers? redering group layers with transparencies can be a hog?

Comment: Yes, I will try turning them off and then repost the result if it runs faster or not.  I have a feeling though that the slowness is occuring within one of the Loops near the Refresh Legend portion.  thx

Comment: I turned some of the group transparencies to 0 and the export speed did not get better.  I think the issue again is that I have three different Loop statements towared the end of the code.  The refresh code portion is the third embedded loop.  Again, I think the slowness starts after the "Do Until IsEmpty(value)" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried that. However, prior to this procedure I had a selection on one of my feature layers. When I cleared that selection before hitting the export legend refresh code the export was remarkably faster. I'm not sure why a feature selection clear would do that, but the code seems to be working fast now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running ILegend.Refresh, instead of Imapsurround.refresh?

Comment: I have not tried that.  However, prior to this procedure I had a selection on one of my feature layers.  When I cleared that selection before hitting the export legend refresh code the export was remarkably faster.  I'm not sure why a feature selection clear would do that, but the code seems to be working fast now.